# How to use ArrayList.addAll()?

Tags: java, arraylist, addition, character

I want to fill an `ArrayList` with these characters +,-,*,^ etc. How can I do this without having to add every character with `arrayList.add()`?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

[Collections.addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29) is what you want.

```
Collections.addAll(myArrayList, '+', '-', '*', '^');
```

Another option is to pass the list into the constructor using [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) like this:

```
List<Character> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('+', '-', '*', '^'));
```

If, however, you are good with the arrayList being fixed-length, you can go with the creation as simple as `list = Arrays.asList(...)`. [Arrays.asList specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) states that it returns a **fixed-length** list which acts as a bridge to the passed array, which could be not what you need.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have an `ArrayList` that contains characters, you could do this:

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList('+', '-', '*', '^'));
```

Comment: `Collections.addAll` is a better way to go, as it simply iterates through given items adding all of them to the list, while with `Arrays.asList` you would create a temporary `List` object to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google guava as such:

```
ImmutableList<char> dirs = ImmutableList.of('+', '-', '*', '^');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `asList` method with varargs to do this in one line:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList('+', '-', '*', '^');
```

If the list does not need to be modified further then this would already be enough. Otherwise you can pass it to the ArrayList constructor to create a mutable list:

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList('+', '-', '*', '^'));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("+","-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays` class in Java which will return you an `ArrayList` :

```
final List<String> characters = Arrays.asList("+","-");
```

You will need a bit more work if you need a `List<Character>`.

Comment: Actually, for it to be a `List<Character>` you simply change `"` to `'` and `List<String>` to `List<Character>`. Generics will handle the rest.