# java invert values in object constructor

Tags: java, list

I've question, I create an object with values like this: `Edge edge = new Edge(vertice1, vertice2, weight);` and add this to myEdgesList.add(edge);`

Is there any way in Java to create the same list but with inverted line1 with line2 like this: `Edge edge = new Edge(vertice2, vertice1, weight);` and add it to the same list.

```
LinkedList<Edge> edgesList = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Edge> secondInverted = new LinkedList<>();
    CSVReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        String[] line;
        while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            Vertex one = findVertexByName(verticesList, line[0]);
            Vertex second = findVertexByName(verticesList, line[1]);
            edgesList.add(new Edge(one, second, Integer.parseInt(line[2])));
            secondInverted.add(new Edge(second, one, Integer.parseInt(line[2])));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<Edge> newList = new ArrayList<>(edgesList);
    newList.addAll(edgesList);
    return newList;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Of course. Have you tried anything? Is there a specific problem? Or are you asking us to write code for you?

Comment: The answer seems to be in the question...

Comment: I've tried write it but it has in one list another line2 and line 1 objects than in the another lists. They must be the same objects inside.

Comment: Maybe you could show me any example, please

Comment: Probably one and second objects are not the same, because program works if I hardcode all objects

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your problem. You want to add shape once with line1 and line2 as parameters and then once more with line2 and line1 as parameters? 
Like

```
    Shape s1 = new Shape(line1, line2, weight);
Shape s2 = new Shape(line2, line1, weight);
list.add(s1);
list.add(s2);
```

Comment: line1 and line2 are objects and I want the same objects in second list, they can't have another place in memory, they must be identical

Comment: If they are objects, you are only giving the reference to them to the shapes when creating them,  they should be the same objects.

How did you determinate that they're not the same?

Comment: Check by equals, or if I print them they've another numbers

Comment: But to all I know, that shouldn't be the case. Can you provide your full code? Maybe that will help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the added list be secondInverted?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple ways, depending when You are creating the new list.
If You want to make them simultaneously, create both shapes:

```
Shape shape = new Shape(line1, line2, weight);
Shape shape2 = new Shape(line2, line1, weight);
myShapeList.add(shape);
myShapeList2.add(shape2);
```

If you want to make it later on, You could either:
1. clone Your myShapeList, and loop through it swapping the attributes ( if You have a setter and getter in Your object )
2. Create a new myShapeList2, and `for(i=0;i<myShapeList.size();i++)` create a new Shape, with `line1 = myShapeList[i].line2` and `line2 = myShapeList[i].line1`, and add it in the new list.
They could be predefined ( like when You make Your First list ), or You can get them with a getter in your object.

Post Your code if You try to make some progress and have any issues.
**UPDATE**
To return a joint new list consisting both Your lists try:

```
List<Edge> newList = new ArrayList<>(edgesList);
newList.addAll(secondInverted);
List<Edge> invertedList = new ArrayList<>(secondInverted);
```

You can check out more info about joining lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273440/adding-one-list-to-another-list-in-java), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985432/how-to-use-arraylist-addall).

Comment: try to create a simple example, if it wont work, just post it

Comment: @george You want to return two lists: the original, and the inverted one ?

Comment: I need to join them together